# For statement solution

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm just really confused on why there's an error at the for statement line. This is literally code from a tutorial that I can't run because there's an error at line 3

```
class RoundOne{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i =0,i<10,i++){
            System.out.println("The number is: "+i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `,` to `;` in your for loop.

Comment: Change the comma to semicolon. That is how you separate statement in Java, using semicolon, not comma.

Comment: am not sure that is how it is in the tutorial, you just copied it wrong and claimed that's how it was.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i =0;i<10;i++){
        System.out.println("The number is: "+i);
    }
```

You wrote , instead of ;

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop instead of

```
for(int i =0,i<10,i++)
```

write

```
for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

For loops use `;` between the parts, not `,`

```
class RoundOne {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("The number is: " + i);
        }
    }
}
```